# Get javascript code from html file

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am trying to get the javascript code from an html file using C# and regular expressions.
The code I use now is the following:

```
string js = Regex.Replace(code, @"^.*?\<script\s?.*?\>((.|\r\n)+?)\<\/script\>.*$", "$1", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

But when I use this I get the full html code with the script-tags stripped.

Can someone help me with this?

---

I use the html agility pack now with the following code:

```
var hwObject = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(code);
        foreach (var script in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("script").ToArray())
        {
            string js = script.InnerText;
            HtmlTextNode text = (HtmlTextNode)script.ChildNodes.Single(d => d.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text);
            text.Text = TrimJs(js);
        }
```

But only the last script tag get's replaced. The javascripts before just disappear.

Comment: If you're at liberty for such a decision, I'd say you should use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.

Comment: from what I understand you want to get only the script, and what you get is everything but the script ?

Comment: I get the html and the script but the script-tags hav disappeared.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should take a look at [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

It is generally much easier to parse HTML using an xml based parser than using regular expressions.

You could use something like this:

```
HtmlWeb hwObject = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument htmldocObject = hwObject.Load("http://www...");
foreach(var script in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("script").ToArray()) 
{ 
    string s = script.InnerText;
    // Modify s somehow
    HtmlTextNode text = (HtmlTextNode)script.ChildNodes
                        .Single(d => d.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text);
    text.Text = s;
}
htmldocObject .Save("file.htm");
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I feel compelled to say, in agreement with @Ryan Gross, that HTML is not a regular language, and using regular expressions to parse HTML is generally not a good idea.

Comment: This looks great, can I also replace the code between the script tags with something else?

Comment: The InnerText property is read only, but I think you could try setting the Text property.

Comment: Is it possible to load a local file or a string? I have tried, but it won't load a local file.

Comment: HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load("file.htm");

Comment: now once I edited the tags, how can I make a string of this object?

Comment: doc.Save("file.htm");  I'll edit my post to include all of this.

Comment: Thank you, but script does not have an option Text. So I still haven't been able to change the text.

Comment: Sorry... I forgot that you'd need to search for the text node that is contained within the script tag.  I updated the answer

Comment: It works great now, thank you. Only one problem: if there are more then one script tag on the page, only the last one get's replaced. The first one just dissapears.

Comment: hmm... I'm not sure why that would happen.  I just set up a dummy project and ran the code, and it worked for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a mistake in my trimJs function.
Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `"^.*?"` and `".*$"`, as this is why everything is included, and there is no reason to use Replace when you are looking for a substring. Just use the Regex.Match method and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, but I want to replace the javascript later in the code. This was just to test if I can get the javascript code.

Comment: Ok, well it might be because you have empty scripts on your page then.  
Try this:  
`\<script.*?\>((.|\r\n)*?)\<\/script\>`

Answer (score 0):

Drop the .* (use the following regexp: `\<script\s?.*?\>((.|\r\n)+?)\<\/script\>`)